# I would like to find all unique distinct values in a row of cells, ignoring blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to cobine together all unique distinct values from a row of cells into one cell. I  want to ignore a cell that is blank. For example if i have A B A BLANK C in a row of cells the result produces A,B,,C but i would like it to produce A,B,C and ignore the blank cell .

[image: IMG:]

I have tried the code below, but it adds an additional comma for blanks. Is there a way to fix this code to account for blanks.

```
Function CombineUnique(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String 

Dim xCell As Range
Dim xDic As Object
Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each xCell In xRg
    xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
Next
CombineUnique = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)
Set xDic = Nothing
End Function
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your For Each loop to:

```
    If xCell.Value <> "" Then
        xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
    End If
```

Your function will be:

```
Function CombineUnique(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String 

Dim xCell As Range
Dim xDic As Object
Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each xCell In xRg
    'Checks if the cell is blank/empty
    If xCell.Value <> "" Then
        xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty        
    End If
Next
CombineUnique = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)
Set xDic = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your response. I just want to ignore a cell that is blank. For example if i have A B A BLANK C in a row of cells the result produces  A,B,,C but i would like it to produce A,B,C and ignore the blank cell

Comment: @Gavers See edit.

Comment: @Gavers See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)